# Glimpse - How to drill down into Webforms methods?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, glimpse

I have previously used Glimpse in as MVC application... this should be included as standard with visual studio, it's fantastic! Anyway...

I have now installed Glimpse in a Webforms project, using NuGet with the following 3 packages:

1.Glimpse Core

2.Glimpse ASP.NET

3.Glimpse Webforms (installed [From here](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/repository/download/bt428/98257:id/Glimpse.WebForms.1.0.1.nupkg) after I hit the known exception bug)

When I use the Timeline, the only information I can access are the page events, which as expected, shows the Load time as the most expensive.  Is there a way to drill down into the load event on the timeline to show the methods called within the load event?

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported at the moment but is foreseen for Glimpse v2. You can track the work going on for that [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/pull/302).

You could in the meanwhile try to work around it by using unsupported internals of Glimpse like mentioned [here on the Glimpse developers list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/getglimpse-dev/ZB0E3G-FHEg/8KYHPxSwDcAJ), but I'll for completeness of the answer copy the content of that post over here :

- Retrieve the `GlimpseRuntime` object from the `HttpContext` : `HttpContext.Current.Application.Get("__GlimpseRuntime")`
- Then publish an `ITimelineMessage` to the MessageBroker: `GlimpseRuntime.Configuration.MessageBroker.Publish(timelineMessage)`
- To populate the properties of your 'ITimelineMessage' implementation you might also need Glimpse's `ExecutionTimer` (-> `HttpContext.Current.Application.Get("__GlimpseTimer")`)